# Retina Macbook Pro Scaling

Tags: resolution, macbook-pro-retina

How does apple "scale" the retina MacBook Pro? Does it actually switch the resolutions or does it just enlarge/shrink the ui elements?

I am asking this because it seems as though the "best resolution" is not the max. Also, they phrase it as "seems like 1280x800, or seems like 1920x1200"[image]

Comment: Related/Duplicate(?): http://superuser.com/questions/612492/retina-macbook-pro-13-inch-screenshot-resolution-is-higher-than-built-in-display/612755#612755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose a "resolution" in this preference panel, you actually modify the size of every component on the screen, but you don't actually switch from a resolution to another one.

A standard 15" MacBook Pro screen resolution is 1440*900. On a MacBook Pro Retina 15", it is 2880*1800.

If you select "Best (Retina)", the screen resolution will be stuck at the native resolution (i.e. 2880*1800) but every component will be as big as if it was a 1440*900 screen resolution : basically, every component/image displayed will be neater since for a single pixel on a standard MacBook Pro, there are 4 on a MBPR.

The same happens when you chose another scale :

- Larger Text : everything is bigger, and looks like if resolution was 1024*640.
- More Space : everything is smaller, and looks like if resolution was 1920*1200

However, as described on [this article](http://www.zdnet.com/how-to-get-the-most-from-your-macbook-pro-retina-display-7000007009/), there are means to choose other resolutions.

Comment: So what does it actually do when you choose 1680x1050 or another resolution other than the "Retina" setting?