# My MacBook Pro is 2560x1600 native resolution, when I capture a screenshot, why it is 2880x1800?

Tags: macos, display, resolution, screenshot, macbook-pro-retina

My MacBook Pro is 2560x1600 native resolution, when I capture a screenshot, why the captured image is 2880x1800? I don't understand.

https://support.apple.com/kb/SP754?locale=en_GB

Retina display
13.3-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit display with IPS technology; 2560-by-1600 native resolution at 227 pixels per inch with support for millions of colors.
Supported scaled resolutions:
1680 by 1050,
1440 by 900,
1024 by 640.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/612492/retina-macbook-pro-13-inch-screenshot-resolution-is-higher-than-built-in-display this might explain why? I guess you could mess with teh settings and take another screenshot and see if the size changes.

Comment: yes, but I don't really understand what it said...

Comment: The "About this mac" section lists the maximum resolution of the display hardware. The "Displays" section within system preferences will show you the active resolution that has been set by the operating system.

Comment: What DrZoo has said is right on the money

Answer (score 0):

Scaling on macOS works just like it's been explained in the other answer. Put it simply:

- Your current display preference is to have things rendered at the same size as if they were rendered on a 1440x900 screen with the same size
- The OS will render your screen in a "virtual" screen that's a multiple of that desired "resolution" so in this case it'll be 2880x1800 (2X). macOS and iOS only work with integer scaling 2X, 3X, 4X...
- Then the high resolution version of your screen will be scaled down to the native resolution of the LCD (2560x1600 in this case)

When you save screenshots the virtual screen is saved instead of the scaled version. Similarly if you choose the resolution as equivalent to 1680x1050 or 1024x640 then the actual rendered screen will be 3360x2100 and 2048x1280